# Can I know if a given method exists?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to know if it's possible in Java to not only check `instanceof` but also something that checks if a given method is available for a generic typed variable.

```
new LruCache<K, V>(size) {
    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(final K key, final V value) {
        // if (value hasmethod getByteCount)
        return super.sizeOf(key, value);
    }
};
```

Does it exists?

Comment: Normally, Java enforces method signatures via class inheritance, so I would have an interface containing `getByteCount ` and checking for `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to restrict `V` to an interface with that method on it. But if you can't do that:

```
boolean hasMethod = false;
try { 
  Method m = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("byteCount", null); 
  hasMethod = true;
}
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
}
catch (SecurityException e) { 
  // you don't have access to the method from your package
}
```

That assumes you have no parameters on that method. Otherwise, pass your parameter types as arguments into `getDeclaredMethod`.

If the method is public, use `getMethod` instead.

**EDIT** The comments are correct in pointing out that this won't get methods from a super type. If you need that you can use this (it skips `Object` methods as all objects have those, so a test for one of those methods being inherited is worthless):

```
<V> boolean hasInheritedDeclaredMethod(V value, String methodName)
{
    Class c = value.getClass();
    boolean hasMethod = false;
    while (!hasMethod && c != Object.class) {
        try { 
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null); 
            hasMethod = true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {  }
        // you don't have access to the method from your package
        catch (SecurityException e) { break; }
        if (!hasMethod && c != Object.class)
            c = c.getSuperclass();
    }
    return hasMethod;
}
```

Comment: I believe it throws NoSuchMethodException if the method is not there.

Comment: @watery. It does - I had forgotten, correcting, thank you. It throws a security exception too if you don't have access to a private/protected method - I was adding that in as you were writing.

Comment: Does getDeclaredMethod() return method from super class?

Comment: @StanislavL. Yes, no, .... no. It doesn't For that you would need getClass().getSuperClass()

Comment: Interface is a good point, even if I can't use it in my current case.

Comment: Run this public class ReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method foo=B.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", null);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}

class A {
    protected void foo() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
} java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: B.foo()

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils

```
public static Method findMethod(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?>... paramTypes)
```

to get method from the class or super class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing that you are asking, is not exactly the same thing, as the problem you are trying to solve. With java generics, you could do this type safe the following way:

You could simply create an interface, that has `getByteCount()`:

```
interface IByteCountable { // some descriptive name
    int getByteCount();
}
```

Then create a derived class from `LruCache`, which enforces type correctness:

```
class MyLruCache<K, V extends IByteCountable> extends LruCache<K, V> {
    @Override protected int sizeOf(final K key, final V value) {
        // compiler can check this, no reflection
        int byteCountOfValue = value.getByteCount(); 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can only create instances of `MyLruCache`, which has some type as `V` which implements `IByteCountable`